# How to save an SVG image in mySQL (from Python 3.6)

Tags: python, mysql, svg, sqlalchemy

How can one save a large SVG image in a mySQL table?
My problem is that my SVGs are up to 200K symbols, which appears to be too much to save them in my table. 
When trying to save as TEXT, Python (using Python 3.6 with Anaconda), python/sqlalchemy tells me the following:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pymysql.err.DataError) (1406, "Data too long for column 'cantons_svg' at row 27") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO  ...]

Comment: What data type is your column ``cantons_svg``?

Comment: it's TEXT. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Have you tried to set it as BLOB type?

Comment: Yes, I set the Datatype of the mySQL field to "BLOB" and "LONGTEXT", but that didn't seem to do the trick. I should note that i'm first putting the large SVG String into a pandas dataframe (which works fine), and then try to save that dataframe with: df.to_sql('df', con=engine, if_exists='replace').

Comment: `if_exists='replace'` replaces the table every time, so even if you `ALTER TABLE` in MySQL, `to_sql` will overwrite that. You need to specify `dtype` in `to_sql`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today when I try to store videos into tidb. I am using flask as backend framework and sqlalchemy as ORM, connecting to by database with mysql python connector.
the log is as follow:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pymysql.err.DataError) (1406, "Data too long for column 'video' at row 1")
[SQL: INSERT INTO videos (user_id, token_id, video) VALUES (%(user_id)s, %(token_id)s, %(video)s)]
```

I found that there is few advise about this situation, amoung those, one suggest me to see if there are any self-defined storage-type in sqlalchemy. It seems quite complicated.(if anyone find a doc or something that giving a clearly guidance about this, please tell me).

As for me, I just use BLOB type of sqlalchemy to init the database. And use

```
alter  table videos modify  column video  LongBlob DEFAULT NULL ；
```

munualy change the column type. This work fine with me.